# Display Waypoints with "walking" travelMode on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to put some Waypoints in a Map. The problem is that I am specifying the travelMode but the Waypoints do not use my travel mode, apparently waypoints used "driving" travel mode, and I want to use "walking".

[image: the problem]

As you can see, the route is not the best route to walk.

Here is my code:

```
route = map.drawRoute({
    origin: [origin.lat, origin.lng],
    destination: [destination.lat, destination.lng],
    travelMode: 'walking',
    strokeColor: '#ff9900',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 6,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
});
```

Also every waypoint have: `stopover: true`.

And idea? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The string 'walking' is not a [TravelMode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TravelMode)

```
route = map.drawRoute({
    origin: [origin.lat, origin.lng],
    destination: [destination.lat, destination.lng],
     travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING,
    strokeColor: '#ff9900',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 6,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am using a framework named GMaps.js, and you can use travelMode with a string, the framework convert the string into: "google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING".

Comment: Perhaps that infromation should be included in your question (as well as the coordinates required to repeat the issue).  Does your framework support waypoints with the walking travelMode?

Answer (score 0):

In gmaps, by default, the travelMode is `walking`, and each waypoint must have its `location` as an instance of `google.maps.LatLng`, not an array with latitude and longitude (like `origin` or `destination`). Also, according the Google Maps API reference:

> Directions will be calculated from the origin to the destination by way of each waypoint in this array. The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination. Maps API for Business customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination. Waypoints are not supported for transit directions.

Comment: Thank you, I have this code for the waypoints:
    obj.waypoints.forEach(function(point) {
        waypts.push({
            location: new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng),
            stopover: true,
        });
        addMarker(point.lat, point.lng, wayPointIcon);
    });